# convert a wav file from GSM to PCM

Tags: audio, wav

I have thousands of GSM wav files, generated by a phone recording system. I need to run these through a speech-to-text engine (Nuance) and this appears to work only with PCM files.
I know nothing about these formats, but would need a programmatic (scripting) way to convert GSM to PCM.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can do it. You need to supply the sample rate and channel count of the gsm file though because it doesn't contain any header information.  Something like this:

`sox input.gsm -r 8000 -c 1 -w -s ouput.wav`

Comment: so -w and -s don't appear to be supported options `sox.exe WARN getopt: option 'w' not recognized`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?